# error in solutions? MIT single variable calculus - Simplifying formula for tangent line

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, tangent-line

Question 1C-4 d) located [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/problem-set-1/MIT18_01SC_pset1prb.pdf) states:

> Write an equation for the tangent line for the following questions:
>   d) $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x} $ at $x = a$.

By my workings:

$f'(a) = (\frac{-1}{2})a^\frac{-3}{2}$

Therefore, the equation of the tangent line at $x = a$ is:

$y = (\frac{-1}{2})a^\frac{-3}{2}[x-a] + \frac{1}{\sqrt a}$

**My questions:**

- The solutions pdf located [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/problem-set-1/MIT18_01SC_pset1sol.pdf) states that the formula for the tangent line at $x = a$ is 
  $y = (\frac{-1}{2})a^\frac{3}{2}[x-a] + \frac{1}{\sqrt a}$. The difference to mine is that I have a negative exponent to the first $a$. Is the solution correct?
- The solutions say that the equation for the tangent line at $x = a$ simplifies to $y = -a^\frac{-3}{2}x + (\frac{3}{2})a^\frac{-1}{2}$. Could you show me how to get to this simplified solution, explicitly stating each step and  which rules have been applied to get to it?

Thank you.

Comment: I think I've seen this question before here on MSE, and I'm pretty sure the MIT solution is wrong. [here] [1] is the other question.

[1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348898/equation-for-tangent-line-for-fx-1-sqrtx-at-x-a

Comment: Your solution is correct. There is a typo on MIT's solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the simplifcation:

$$ y = -\frac{1}{2}a^{-\frac{3}{2}}(x-a)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} $$
$$ y = \frac{1}{2}a^{-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot a -\frac{1}{2}a^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cdot x + a^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\ \text{(multiplication, and definition of power and square root)} $$
$$ y = \frac{1}{2}a^{-\frac{1}{2}} + a^{-\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{2}a^{-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot x \\ \text{(reordering)} $$
$$ y = \frac{3}{2}a^{-\frac{1}{2}} - a^{-\frac{3}{2}}x \\ \text{(summation)} $$

As was to be shown.

(I am not too familiar with the syntax, I hope it is clear though)